# How can I automatically call a function after construction?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq object that needs to automatically assign another object to a property at construction. The object being assigned depends on the object making the call.

**What I want to do:**

```
public RigAction()
{
    this.DueDate = new DueDate(this);
}
```

That, however, throws this Exception:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

**What works**

```
public RigAction()
{
}

public void getDueDate() {
    this.DueDate = new DueDate(this);
}
```

But then I have to do this whenever I instantiate the object:

```
var action = db.RigActions.First();
action.getDueDate();
```

Is there a workaround?

**Update**

the DueDate class:

```
public class DueDate
{
    private DateTime dueDate;
    public RigActionTypeClass.RigActionType a;

    public DueDate(RigAction action)
    {
        this.dueDate = action.RigActionType.FrequencyType.GetOriginalDueDateForAction(action);
    }

    public DueDate(UniqueRigAction action)
    {

    }

   public override string ToString()
   {
      return this.dueDate.ToString();
   }
}
```

Comment: You should use FirstOrDefault, that will return a instance of the object if It's doesn't exists in your database.

Comment: How is the DueDate object being used?

Comment: @Fals the object does exist in the database though, when using method 2, everything works as expected.

Comment: Sounds like your error is in the action.RigActionType.... you can definitely set properties like that in the constructor. Which value is "null" in the debugger?

Comment: @Bort I just added the DueDate class to my question - does that help?

Comment: It would appear that, within your constructor, you need to initialize some other members of that instance before creating the due date.  Your code shows nothing else in your constructor, do you actually have other stuff in your real code?

Comment: @Servy it's a Linq object, Linq is handling all of the initialization behind the scenes. You are definitely correct, what do you recommend I do?

Comment: @anwyatt You have shown no references to any LINQ objects at all.  LINQ is handling none of the initialization behind the scenes, from what you have shown.  You also didn't answer the question of whether or not your real code is actually doing other things in the constructor to initialize other data.

Comment: There is definitely missing code here.  Why show us fake code that works when your real code is broken?  Show us the real code.

Comment: @Servy Linq uses empty constructors... I'm not entirely sure what you would like me to show you. `RigActionType` is an `EntityRef` if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @J... This is real... I left out the properties that reference my table, but seriously - Linq uses an empty constructor during initialization. Why do you need to see the ORM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you try to create the `DueDate` object, before you initialized `RigActionType`, or that `GetOriginalDueDateForAction` trying to access such (uninitialized) object of `RigAction`.

First initialize all the needed data for `DueDate`, and only after that, create the `DueDate` object.

Comment: I am 90% sure you are correct. Can you elaborate on possible solutions/workarounds?

Comment: `DouDate` is accessing data of `RigAction`. The exception is thrown (if I'm right) because that data isn't initialized yet (you creating it in the ctor, which is the initializer). You may try one of too things: 1) First initialize all the data which is required by `DueDate`, and only after that create it. 2) Try to lazily load `DueDate`, which mean, store the `RigAction` object in the `DueDate` class, and calculate `dueDate` (the field) only when you actually need it.

Comment: I think I may have to go with option 2, since Linq is handling the initialization - I'm not sure how to tell my constructor to wait until after initialization to continue.

Comment: There is a class to help with lazy loading... so `dueDate` should be declared as `private Lazy<DateTime> dueDate;` and in the constructor you should init it as `this.dueDate = new Lazy<DateTime>(() => action.RigActionType.FrequencyType.GetOriginalDueDateForAction(action));` ... to access its value, just use `dueDate.Value`, and it would be calculated only the first time you actually call it...